# How can I get Gnome-Flashback to work on a new install of 20.04 on a brand new machine?

Tags: 20.04, gnome-flashback

I've just installed 20.04 on a brand new machine. As I have a USB stick to reset the machine to factory defaults and an older production machine, I'm experimenting on the new one to get it set up the way I want it, before switching.

The first thing, of many, I need is to get Gnome-Flashback up and running. After installing Synaptic, I used it to install Gnome-Flashback & the 2 other packages Synaptic suggested and Gnome-Panel along with the 41 packages Synaptic suggested.

Still no joy.

It's a new install on a brand new machine with a brand new HHD.

What more do I need to do?

Comment: Install `gnome-session-flashback`. It should provide required files to start session from display manager.

Comment: Thanks! I just checked. It's already installed. When I installed gnome-panel Synaptic suggested and installed gnome-session-flashback.

Comment: Well then you have everything needed to be able to select GNOME Flashback session. Did you restart? In case display manager ignores new files after it is started...

Comment: It seems that it was the change in the login screen.

Comment: It seems that it was the change in the login screen(s) between 16.04 and 20.04.

I was accustomed to the login screen on 16.04 where the desktop and the user account can be selected up front, before entering the password. Furthermore, the desktop selection icon is right there beside the user account selection box. 

The 20.04 login screen requires the user account to be selected first. Only then, on the password screen, can the desktop be selected via a small icon at the bottom right corner of the screen. (Almost invisible.)

So, this issue is resolved.